# Compiling native wxWidgets applications on Cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, cross-platform, wxwidgets

I would like to develop cross-platform applications using wxWidgets on Linux and then port them to Windows using Cygwin.
It is desirable to have a quick way to distribute the compiled application binaries for Windows.
Do someone knows a way to compile and distribute wxWidgets applications using Cygwin, but preferably without needing to ask users to install a full Cygwin distribution?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the MinGW toolchain -- it compiles native and stand-alone Windows binaries, no need for Cygwin.dll (and its licensing implications) on the target machine.

Search for "mingw" in the Cygwin setup. You will find both the GCC toolchain and appropriate wxWidgets libraries.

(Not sure if these are part of the basic Cygwin package or need [Cygwin Ports](https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) as well, I effectively always use both anyway.)

---

That being said, **not** using the Cygwin.dll of course means you cannot use its POSIX API. Instead of targeting that, you will have to find other libraries to provide you with portability. However, since Cygwin provides all kinds of precompiled MinGW libraries -- including wxWidgets, Boost, ICU, pthreads, Glib, you-name-it -- that shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I need some POSIX operations and have a native window to pop up for showing some data.

Comment: @Fernando: What kind of POSIX operations would that be that you'd need on a Windows box and cannot replace with something from a portable support library? The libraries I mentioned (wxWidgets, Boost, ICU, pthreads, Glib) are really quite exhaustive already, and that is just a fraction of what's available for MinGW...

Comment: I have 3 targets: a Linux embed system running on ARM and without much libraries options, due to it's small memory; a full Linux desktop and a Windows desktop.
Everything that I wish is to continue to compile my embedded application with just a "g++ sock_app.c" (which works very well) and have a desktop application using that very same piece of code almost untouched.

I have been able to compile wxwidgets, but for now, I just need to remove the X dependency on Windows.

Comment: Notice that with MinGW you can also cross-compile from Linux to Windows, so you don't need to do any development under Windows if you don't want to.

Comment: @Fernando: Well, you cannot get exactly what you want. Either you go MinGW, which requires doing without Cygwin's POSIX layer, which requires figuring out what exactly your POSIX requirements are, and replacing them with something portable (or finding appropriate Windows wrappers). Or you go Cygwin, which requires shipping the Cygwin.dll and making your code GPL.

Comment: Actually, I don't have any issues distributing my code in GPL.
My main problem is just the X dependency on Cygwin.
Is it impossible to have Cygwin compiling wxWidgets with it's posix functions and have a native Windows application?